# Fragment content is hidden behind BottomNavigationView when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, android-nestedscrollview

I've researched through this quite heavily and am at a loss on what to do - I have some content in a fragment that is being clipped off by the BottomNavigation bar in the activity and am not sure what to do.  I've tried adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the NestedScrollView but the bottom piece of the content (the names of the locations) is still being cut off - there's probably an easy fix for this but I can't figure it out.  The XML for my main activity and the "home" fragment is as follows:

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/home_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/navbarBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

home_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_screen_placeholder" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/airplane_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8_airplane_48"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="286dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/destination_headline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/featured_destinations_headline"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/featured_destinations_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/destination_headline" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/saved_trips_headline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/featured_destinations_recycler_view"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/saved_trips"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/saved_trips_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/saved_trips_headline" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

As an example to show what I mean, [here is the content when the navigation bar is moved out of the way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNgtu.png) and [here is the content with the bar in the way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njvC4.png). I'm thinking that the problem is some sort of margin/padding issue, but can't quite figure out what to fix.

**Edit:** I've create a repository with the relevant code (and a workable emulator example) [here](https://github.com/epitone/test_proj) - please be aware that the code is written in Kotlin, but I don't imagine the issue lies witihn any of the actual code, but more within the layout

Comment: Can you post a simple project with that behavior in github?

Comment: Can you provide code for @layout/app_bar.xml

Comment: can you remove CoordinatorLayout n try

Comment: @azizbekian sure, I'll do it when I get some time tonight after work!

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya done!

Comment: @AmjadKhan I tried that and it didn't help, I still end up with the same result as picture #2

Comment: Could you try with a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout ? and you can remove the CoordinatorLayout inside the home_fragment.xml, it's useless

Comment: @DavidSeroussi Did as you suggested, there was no discernible change - I'll update my post with the new code!

Comment: I think the issue comes from the constant height of the NestedScrollView, and perhaps other messed up constraints. You should try building your layout directly in xml, not in edit mode, and avoiding constants. Try using only constraints that are screen-size independant. If you don't succed I will post a complete answer

Comment: @azizbekian I added a github link in my original post! It contains the most recent updated code (see the answer given below for more context) and at this point, the NestedScrollView has now stopped scrolling entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the expected behavior, I cannot understand that just by reading your question. Having applied [this patch](https://nofile.io/f/kfSCaH97E1j/unnamed.patch), which just includes **home_fragment.xml** layout changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_screen_placeholder"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/airplane_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8_airplane_48"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header_container">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/destination_headline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/featured_destinations_headline"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/featured_destinations_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/destination_headline"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/saved_trips_headline"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/destination_headline" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/saved_trips_headline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/saved_trips"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/featured_destinations_recycler_view" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/saved_trips_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/app_bar"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/saved_trips_headline" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then you'll get this output:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

@Tai M. 
The problem seems to be the **hardcoded** height of the NestedScrollView. Since you are already using ConstraintLayout, you can easily lay this view without having to add another Relative layout.

If you want to have the Header images one on top of the other, please wrap those in a **FrameLayout**. Assign an id to the container and add: 
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerImageContainer"
to the NestedScrollView.

Then you can probably get rid of the RelativeLayout and replace it with another ConstraintLayout to structure the rest of the views using constraints only.

Also, by material design definition, the height of the BottomNavigationView is **56dp** which you can assign directly rather than making it wrap content in the 
    activity_home.xml

```
<ConstraintLayout ...>

    <FrameLayout ...>
        <ImageView .../>

        <ImageView .../>

    </FrameLayout>

    <NestenScrollView ... wrap_content>
        <ConstraintLayout ...>
            <TextView .../>
            <RecyclerView .../>
            <!-- Assign constraints accordingly -->
            <TextView .../>
            <RecyclerView .../>

        </ConstraintLayout>

    </NestenScrollView>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to make sure I follow, when you say to get rid of the relativelayout, you're referring to the one within the NestedScrollView? If that's the case, that's not possible, as NestedScrollViews are only allowed one direct child, so I need some form of layout within it so as not to throw errors.

Comment: @TaiM. I edited the answer a bit. I was trying to add that in the comment, but couldn't do that. This should help.

Comment: Followed your example, but now the content won't scroll at all, the recyclerviews work, but the nestedscrollview itself won't function properly. I think I'm going to create a separate repository with JUST this section of code to see if someone can reproduce the issue I'm going through, I feel that may be easier than just using code snippets.

Comment: I added the github link to the original post!

Comment: @TaiM. I checked out your project and ran it. The scrollView are working as expected. Not as responsive though. Maybe you can try optimize your recyclerView implementation by enabling 
`featuredDestinationsRecycler.setItemViewCacheSize(10)
        featuredDestinationsRecycler.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true`

And, layout manager, set the prefetch as well: 
`featuredDestinationsLayoutManager.initialPrefetchItemCount = 5
        featuredDestinationsLayoutManager.isItemPrefetchEnabled = true`

Please upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ConstraintLayout` you need to set the `layout_height` to `0dp` and the bottom constraint to the top of the `BottomNavigationView`. An example:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```